# Update Manager Error - Invalid Package Name

Tags: updates, package-management, dpkg

I get the following error when trying to perform an update in Ubuntu 12.04 64bit:

```
installArchives() failed: Preconfiguring packages ...
Preconfiguring packages ...
Preconfiguring packages ...
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 40128 package 'foomatic-db-compressed-ppds':
 `Suggests' field, invalid package name `printer5driver-?2300w': character `?' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._')
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `/var/lib/dpkg/available` file is corrupted. So delete or move the current one and create a new file from backup.

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/available ~/Desktop
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
```

Comment: It worked! Packages are installing...

Comment: i have the available-old file currupted as well , what should i do